# Migrate .csproj from .NET Framework 4.5 to .NET Core 2.1.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .NET Core 2.1.1 project, and I am trying to copy the contents from an existing .NET Framework 4.5 project by updating the .csproj file.

I guess there are many different parts that wont't work on a .NET Core 2.1.1 project.

So my main question is how to migrate a .csproj file from .NET Framework 4.5 to .NET Core 2.1.1.

The first thing I need to do is to copy the contents from one project to another:

This is a working .NET Framework 4.5 .csproj line that does exactly that:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <GeneratedMigrationFile>$(IntermediateOutputPath)Migrations.Generated.cs</GeneratedMigrationFile>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <SqlFiles Include="Data\*.sql" />
      <Compile Condition="'@(SqlFiles)' != ''" Include="$(GeneratedMigrationFile)" />
      <EmbeddedResource Include="@(SqlFiles)" />
      <None Include="..\..\_libBinary\FluentMigrator.1.1.1.0\tools\*.*">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <MakeDir Directories="$(IntermediateOutputPath)" />
    <Delete Files="$(GeneratedMigrationFile)" />
    <GenerateMigration Condition="'@(SqlFiles)' != ''" Namespace="$(RootNamespace)" Id="%(SqlFiles.Filename)" FileId="%(SqlFiles.Filename)" Output="$(GeneratedMigrationFile)" />
  </Target>
...
....
```

However, when doing the same in a .NET Core 2.1.1 .csproj, it seems not to be working and the content of the folder is not being copied.

I deleted the following line because it was causing a build error:

```
<GeneratedMigrationFile>$(IntermediateOutputPath)Migrations.Generated.cs</GeneratedMigrationFile>
```

How can I migrate the .csproj file?

Comment: Are both projects ASP.NET Core based? Them just edit your csproj to target the new platform, then update your dependencies, which is very well documented in the ASP.NET Core docs [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 1.x to 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: As for the rest, check [Migrate from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: @Tseng i am checking that now.

Comment: @Tseng I red those 2 articles and they doesn't help me. in my case i already have a working `.net core 2.1.1` application, i am trying to copy code from the `framework 4.5` application (i am using the `framework 4.5, just for reference- i don't need to migrate it to `.net core 2.1.1`, just to implement his `csproj` code alike, in the `.net core 2.1.1` application- and the first thing that doesn't work, is the code i quoted in the main post.

Comment: You still haven't clarified if your .NET Framework 4.5 is an ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core Application. ASP.NET Core is a complete rewrite, while the API surface is similar its completely different

Comment: the poroject that i want to copy `csproj` from is ASP.NET project with target framework 4.5, the project that i want to copy the `csproj` to, is ASP.NET Core 2.1 Application

Comment: Try `<Target Name="BeforeBuild" BeforeTargets="Build" ... >` instead then. the new csproj files have a new (slim and less verbose) structure. The `BeforeTargets`/`AfterTargets` determine at which stage it will be invoked